# C++ prevent inherit specific public member of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

How can I prevent a public member to be inherited by it's derived class? Like, if I have this:

```
class Person {
    public:
        enum { MALE, FEMALE, BOTH };
        Person(std::string name, int gender)
            : _name(name)
        {
            switch (gender) { /* processing here */ }
        }
    protected:
        std::string _name;
};

class Male : public Person {
    public:
        Male(std::string name)
            : _name(name, 0) { }
};
```

The reason I want to do this is, I want to be able to instantiate a person class with something like:

```
Person person("The Name", Person::MALE);
```

But, because the `enum` is public this is also available:

```
Male::MALE
Male::FEMALE
Male::BOTH
```

which doesn't make any sense anymore. How can I prevent the derived class to be able to access those enum values, but make it available for public from the base class?

Comment: Why not define the Enum outside `Person` ?

Comment: `class Male` is not inheriting from `class Person`

Comment: IMHO having the enum within the person class adds nothing and is contextually wrong because it describes something which is non-specific to a Person or a derivative of person. Put it outside the class and your problem goes away.

Comment: Your example code has nothing to do with polymorphism. Also in your code `Male` doesn't inherit from `Person`. Otherwise it would have to call the `Person(std::string, int)` constructor. Then `std::string _name` can be `private` instead of `protected` and will be maintained through the parent class instead of through `Male` itself. In the `Person(std::string, int)` constructor you should expect your enum type instead of a plain `int`. The prefered way in C++ is to use an `enum class` and not an anonymous `enum`. Just define the `enum class` outside `Person` but within the same `namespace`.

Comment: sorry,  i mean `class Male : public person`. Typo ... edited

Comment: Also when inheriting `Male` from Person it doesn't make any sense to have that `enum` as the gender is defined by the inheriting classes and `Person` should most likely be abstract then. Could it be that you're trying to implement a factory?

Comment: @foobar The main purpose of `Person` class existence is to be inherited, so there will be very rare or even no `Person` object in my code. I didn't make it an abstract class because, in case I need a standalone `Person` object.

Comment: Why don't you use a factory design pattern

Comment: @Brahim What is that? Sorry, I am too slow :)

Comment: It is an object oriented pattern. The idea is to create a Factory class that is responsible for the creation of the persons. check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on keeping the `enum` within the base class, you can place the `enum` in a protected section.

```
class Person {
    protected:
        enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE, BOTH };
        Person(std::string name, Gender gender)
            : _name(name)
        {
            switch (gender) { /* processing here */ }
        }
        std::string _name;
    public:
        virtual ~Person () {}
        //...
};
```

A class that derives from `Person` publicly will still have access to the `enum` values, but users of the derived class will not.

```
class Male : public Person {
    public:
        Male (std::string name) : Person(name, MALE) {}
        //...
};
```

Thus, a `Male` can use `MALE`, but users of `Male` will not see `Male::MALE`, `Male::FEMALE`, nor `Male::BOTH`, which was one of your original issues. As to your questions, you don't really want to deny the derived class access, since you want the derived class to be able to specify the `Gender`. And you should not really allow any direct users of `Person`. Instead, a user of `Person` picks one of the correct derived classes, which will then establish `Gender` properly.

```
class Female : public Person {
    public:
        Female (std::string name) : Person(name, FEMALE) {}
        //...
};

class Transgender : public Person {
    public:
        Transgender (std::string name) : Person(name, BOTH) {}
        //...
};

std::shared_ptr<Person> p = std::make_shared<Female>("Beth");
```

Comment: He wants the users of `Person` to have access to the `enum`, but not derived classes. So the problem is actually the other way round.

Comment: @foobar: For that use case, I would instead define helper derived classes for each `enum`.

Comment: Then please adjust the answer to satisfy the question.

Comment: @foobar: Hmm... that wasn't really the intent of the answer, but I have extended it with why this way will work.

Comment: In the question the author states: "..., but make it available for public from the base class." If you set it to protected, this is not the case anymore.

Comment: @Flovdis: Sometimes the answer is: Don't try to do that. In this case, it isn't that great of a burden, since it is possible to create a derived `Person` that exposes the `enum` values.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in the OP suggest a rethinking of your design, and probably that is the best alternative.

Still, if you want to keep up with what you wrote in the answer, one possibility is to derive `protected`ly from your base class

```
class Person {
    public:
        enum { MALE, FEMALE, BOTH };
        Person(std::string name, int gender)
            : _name(name)
        {
            switch (gender) { /* processing here */ }
        }
    protected:
        std::string _name;
};

class Male : protected Person
{          //^^^^^^^^^

    public:
        Male(std::string name)
            : Person(name, 0) { }

        void foo() { FEMALE; }  // still ok, a public field derived protected'ly is accessible
};

int main()
{
    Male male("Joe");
    male.MALE;     //error, cannot call the enum from outside the class
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean `Male` class cannot has public functions at all?

Comment: Now you can't do `Person* p = new Male("Joe");`, that isn't really good.

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be a literate one, there is no problem with the code per se, but in viewing the code as a language reflecting common notions.

In this sense i would suggest the following answer:

have a factory (or factory method) where the enum is public only in that factory. In other words create a new factory `Human` and have all base and derived classes using `Human` enums. Then the base class can still be `Person` but `Person` does not have any enum `MALE`/`FEMALE`/etc.. only the `Human` factory does, and it is not a base class that is subclassed. This would result in code which can be read literaly like this:

```
Person person("The Name", Human::MALE);
```

You can also use `Gender` factory (instead of `Human`) like this (to be even more literate and separate the inter-dependencies):

```
Person person("The Name", Gender::MALE);
```

Note that a **base class includes the lowest common denominator that all derived classes must share**. So since the derived classes `Male` `Female` etc are not supposed to share the `gender enum` then it should not be part of the base class, but a class or construct in itself which is then used by `Person` classes and its derivatives.

Answer (score -1):

Simple make the `Person` class abstract using a protected constructor:

```
class Person {
public:
    enum Gender {
        MALE,
        FEMALE,
        BOTH
    };

protected:
    // Protected constructor can only be called from subclasses.
    Person(std::string name, Gender gender)
        : _name(name)
    {
        switch (gender) { /* processing here */ }
    }

protected:
    std::string _name;
};

class Male : public Person {
    public:
        Male(std::string name)
            : Person(name, MALE)
        {
        }
};
```

If the gender is anyway independent from the Person class, just move it out of the class:

```
enum Gender {
    GenderMale,
    GenderFemale,
    GenderBoth
};

class Person //...
class Male // ...
```

You can also encapsulate the Gender into a own class:

```
class Gender {
public:
    enum Type { Male, Female, Both };
    Gender(Type type); 
    Gender(const Gender &copy);
    Gender& operator=(Gender &assign);
public:
    bool operator==(const Gender &other) const;
    // etc.
public:
    std::string toString() const;
};
```